# How to add data in date format Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the model:

```
$tour = new Tour();
```

After I add data to object `$tour`:

```
$tour->date_start_at = $request->date_start_at;
$tour->date_end_at = $request->date_end_at;
$tour->save();
```

The fields `date_start_at` and `tour->date_end_at` are `datetime` type in database.

Also in my model I have:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at','date_start_at', 'date_end_at'];
```

When  I try to save it I get:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:

Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Data missing
```

Comment: and what does `$request->date_start_at` look like, are you sure it isn't `$request->input('date_start_at')`?

Comment: This is input field from outside and it equals: `"08/24/2016"`

Comment: Seems I need convert this date to datetime

Comment: How ever you got the answer for your query, just for your information if you want to save with some format your can use :  `Carbon::parse($request->date_start_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to parse the data:

```
$tour->date_start_at = Carbon::parse($request->date_start_at);
$tour->date_end_at = Carbon::parse($request->date_end_at);
$tour->save();
```